# In the pygame module for Python 3, is it possible to draw a rectangle whose outline colour is different to the inner colour?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am drawing a grid for a board and am currently using the formua:

```
pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,colour,(xCoord, yCoord, Width, Height),fill)
```

(I define these parameters later on)

I found out that if i set the 'fill' to 0 it will make a rectangle with one filled colour, and if I set it to 1, it makes a rectangle with just the outline of the specified colour.

However, I would like to create a rectangle that has a different outline colour to its fill colour - is this possible?

If not ill have to just make a slightly smaller rectangle in front of the other one - which sounds really messy.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that in one command. But it really isn't that messy to create those two triangles - two simple lines. This will draw a thin single-pixel rectangle around the inner one:

```
pygame.draw.rect(display, color1, (x, y, width, height), width=1)
pygame.draw.rect(display, color2, (x+1, y+1, width-1, height-1))  # Rects are filled by default
```